# variable does not modify in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a variable named ***w*** in my code, I have declared it globally and I am changing its value inside a function but when I print it outside the function it is undefined instead of showing its modified value, kindly help.

```
    var w;
    $http.get("https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D%22islamabad%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys")
    .success(function (response) {
        var result = response.query; 
        var temp=result.results.channel.item.condition.temp;
        var text=result.results.channel.item.condition.text;    
        window.w = $scope.weather = temp+" "+text;
    });
    window.alert(w);
```

Comment: One word sums it up ... ***asynchronous*** !

Comment: The value of 'w' only changes within the scope of the function. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp is a good place to look to get a good idea of scope.

Comment: @MCMXCII - w3schools is never a good place to look for anything !

Comment: Your alert gets called before your _.get_ Set `w="something"` initially ,you will get alert with "something"